# Syntax- X-bar theory- verbal Domain

Tags: syntax

Please can someone explain to me what a 'parallel pattern in the verbal domain of French' mean.

Comment: Too broad, you should provide a context for this discussion. Can you cite some examples, or authors, or highlight this point of 'parallel verb pattern' further?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I understand (or approve of) X-bar theory, perhaps the parallelism intended is between the structures of clauses and nominals.  This is the basis of McCawley's version of X-bar theory.  He argues that in nominalization, the structure of V-bar is parallel with the structure of N-bar, replacing "V" by "N".